# Angular Routing - Wait for previous resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, resolve, route-provider

I have an angular route as below:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/:one/:two/:three?', {
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        resolve: {
            login: function(LoginService) {
                return LoginService.login();
            },
            admin: function($route, LoginService) {
                return LoginService.admin($route.current.params.one, $route.current.params.two, $route.current.params.three);
            }
        }
    });
```

The issue is that the second resolve, admin, depends on the first resolve completing (LoginService.admin() calls ensureAuthenticated, which requires LoginService.login() to complete else it just fails).

Is there a way to tell the admin resolve to wait for the login resolve?

Thanks for any help/advice you can provide.

Comment: If no better solution is found, you could use $timeout, to wait for login resolve a bit. Otherwise, I think this post might be helpful http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved/

Comment: Thanks, I used that post originally for setting it up, but his "books" and "movies" are independent so there's no handling of my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inject the first resolve result (`login` in your case) to the the 2nd resolve, then that resolve will be delayed until that value is loaded. If it's not loaded or there is an error, it will not trigger:

```
$stateProvider.state('/admin/:one/:two/:three?', {
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        resolve: {
            login: function(LoginService) {
                return LoginService.login();
            },
            admin: function($route, LoginService, login) { //here we injected login
                return LoginService.admin($route.current.params.one, $route.current.params.two, $route.current.params.three);
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**: Changed the answer, at the moment I only know this to work with `$stateProvider`.

Comment: This returns an error:
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loginProvider <- login

Comment: @Gary There's a chance it is only supported in `$stateProvider`. Since I couldn't find a documentation for it I thought it might be supported in `$routeProvider` as well. Do you have to use the 2nd one ?

Comment: The first one calls the Login api, to log the user in. The the second calls the authentication api to ensure the logged in user is an admin. The second is the important one, it stops non-admins access the URL

Comment: I meant if you have to use the $routeProvider or you can switch to $stateProvider ?

Comment: To be honest I've never looked at stateProvider so I'm not sure. I'll have a look now to see if there are any major differences

Comment: @Gary There aren't many at all, just some syntax changes like "ng-view" to "ui-view" and the dependency in the module. $stateProvider is an improvement on the $urlProvider. I also switched after a while.

Comment: That's quite a lot to change for the code base we have but this is a good idea incase I can't find another solution. In the mean time, I'm going to try add some ensureAdmin request logic in the LoginService.login() and see if that helps

Comment: StateProvider worked, but I'm going with another solution (calling ensureAdmin after login by passing in a checkAdmin variable as true of false)